# Load different parameter file depending on the controller called?

Tags: symfony

I have the following controllers:

```
class CompanyXController extends Controller
{
    public function homepageAction()
    {
        $companyinfo = array('company' => $this->container->getParameter('XConfig'));
        $this->render('hometeplate.twig', $companyinfo);
    }
}

class CompanyYController extends Controller
{
    public function homepageAction()
    {
        $companyinfo = array('company' => $this->container->getParameter('YConfig'));
        $this->render('hometeplate.twig', $companyinfo);
    }
}
```

A lot of code is being duplicated just because of the different parameter strings.

I could just make them both into one abstract class if I could dynamically change what configuration file `$this->container->getParameter('Config');` returns.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [Template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern:

```
class CompanyXController extends BaseCompanyController
{
    public function getConfigParam()
    {
        return 'XConfig';
    } 
}

class CompanyYController extends BaseCompanyController
{
    public function getConfigParam()
    {
        return 'YConfig';
    } 
}

abstract class BaseCompanyController extends Controller
{
    abstract public function getConfigParam();

    public function homepageAction()
    {
        $companyinfo = array('company' => $this->container->getParameter($this->getConfigParam()));

        return $this->render('hometeplate.twig', $companyinfo);
    }
}
```